Метод isFile() и exist() не работают
Пишу приложение для андройд на java и столкнулся с проблемой. Я пытаюсь открыть любой файл в /storage/emulated/0/чтототам.txt и все это увенчивается неудачей. Я пробовал метод listFiles() и возвращает [Ljava.io.File;@cb15277
Сам код
public boolean run_file(File direct, String tar_f) {
    direct = new File(direct.toString() + "/" + tar_f);
       if (direct.isFile()) {
           код далее...

Но при этом работает это
public boolean cd(File c_d, String tar) {
        c_d = new File(c_d.toString() + "/" + tar);
        return c_d.exists();
    }

Может кто-нибудь указать на ошибку, пожалуйста. Разрешение MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE предоставлено
Уточняю!!! Я миллион раз проверил и дальше isFile не идет, он возвращает false

isFile() и exists() проверяют разные вещи. По данному пути может что-то быть, но это что-то может быть не файлом.

Ну и заголовок не отражает смысла вопроса и даже не соответствует тому, что написано в вопросе. Методы работают.

И раз метод listFiles() возвращает [Ljava.io.File;@cb15277, что, собственно, и является простым массивом файлов, то как раз логично предположить, что переданный в этот метод файл является директорией.

@Эникейщик Да, вопрос я задал не точно, но могу сказать, что файл там есть. Я его лично создал. И почему-то мне и тот и другой метод false возвращают. И if немного подредактировал, я одного понять не могу, почему false возвращают оба метода.

Ну например указан неправильный путь

Решил проблему такой шнягой:
File[] files = direct.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isFile();
        }
    });
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(tar_f.trim())) {...


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
